# Error Handling with Android JSON Exception

Tags: java, android, json, google-app-engine

I get this this nice message when the companyTwo value in my datastore is blank:

```
09-09 15:13:52.927: W/System.err(31091): org.json.JSONException: No value for companyTwo
```

What would be a good way to handle this assuming I can only pull from the datastore instead of post a filler value?

```
private static final String TAG_COMPANY ="company";
private static final String TAG_OTHERCOMPANY ="companyTwo";


String company1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_COMPANY);
String othercompany1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_OTHERCOMPANY);
```

Comment: you should check if it is null

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid The JSON item companyTwo is in some contacts and missing in others. So it will work fine if companyTwo is in the JSON, but if not I get the JSON error. I have no way of telling if an entry will have the value of companyTwo or not.

Comment: JSON only supports trying and then catching if you use get function

Comment: otherwise use opt function and then check for null

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid I used the opt function. Works good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
{
String company1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_COMPANY);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
// do whatever you want
}
```

alternatively you can do this

```
String company1 = String.valueOf(jsonObj1.optString(TAG_COMPANY));
```